# ML Engine - Not using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gcloud

I'm trying to train a model in GCloud ML Engine, using one Tesla K80. The program runs, but it's even slower than in a laptop without GPU.

There is a message, which shows that GPU is not running any processes. I haven't change any part of my code for running in GPU because I think Tensorflow decides for you which processes are run in the CPU and whcih ones are run in the GPU.

After the first time I run the code in the cloud, I tried to wrap the graph operations and the optimizer inside `with tf.device('/device:GPU:0')`, but anything changed.

I got this message:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.111 Driver Version: 384.111 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 Tesla K80 Off | 00000000:00:04.0 Off | 0 |
| N/A 61C P8 29W / 149W | 1MiB / 11439MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| No running processes found |
 +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, any idea is welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely your code is using CPU not GPU. Can you share the code?

Comment: If you are using tensorflow and python. Please install tensorflow as `pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Comment: @Ultraviolet On Google's cloud ml engine, you cannot simply run `pip`. Once you specify a certain instance type, Google *should* take care of things automatically.

Comment: @Ultraviolet That said, in the `setup.py` script is a `install_requires` parameter. **DO NOT** specify `tensorflow` there, but (if you must) `tensorflow-gpu`. If the only location you install this is Google Cloud ML, you don't even need to specify the dependency. It's always there.

Answer (score 3):

To train with a GPU, you have to specify what type of node you want to use. This is done in a yaml file which you have to reference when starting the job.

Example for `config.yaml`:

```
trainingInput:
  pythonVersion: "3.5"
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  # standard_gpu provides 1 GPU. Change to complex_model_m_gpu for 4 GPUs
  masterType: standard_gpu
```

Then, when you submit the job, refer to it like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
        --package-path $APP_PACKAGE_PATH \
        --module-name $MAIN_APP_MODULE \
        --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
        --region us-central1 \
        --config config.yaml \
        -- \
```

This *should* ensure that you are running on a "standard_gpu" node using python 3.5. For more info see [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-gpus#submit-job).

As @ultraviolet mentioned in a comment above, to use the GPU you need to use `tensorflow-gpu`, *not* `tensorflow`. This means, that in your `setup.py` file, you *must not* specify `tensorflow` as a requirement. Instead, either don't specify tensorflow at all (it's always provided by the platform) or specify `tensorflow-gpu`.

A valid `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='SOME_NAME',
      version='0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      description='YOUR DESCRIPTION',
      install_requires=[
          'tensorflow-gpu'
      ],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

If you want to make sure that you are not running the whole job on the CPU and spend a lot of money for something you could do on your laptop at home, you could also add a sanity check. E.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print('Failed to find default GPU.')
    sys.exit(1)
```